need help debuggin openssl on ubuntu 16.04 (unable to change root certificate for ISRG Root X1)
(sorry for the formatting, I could not post without setting most of this post as code )
I'm running ubuntu 16.04. openssl is claiming that a sites certificate has expired.
        openssl s_client -connect api.ipgeolocation.io:443 -showcerts
    
    returns :
    depth=4 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
    verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
    notAfter=Sep 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT
    .
    .
    .
    3 s:/C=US/O=Internet Security Research Group/CN=ISRG Root X1
       i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
    .
    .
    .

If I understand correctly:

It's a problem with the root certificate DST Root CA X3
DST Root CA X3 has been invalid for a few years now (it's a wonder why this only started failing a few days ago. I've been using api.ipgeolocation.io using ssl for over a year without any problems)
I need to change the cert used by openssl for verifying step 3 (ISRG Root X1) from the one that uses DST Root CA X3 to a self signed one.

I have:

downloaded a self signed version cert for ISRG Root X1 (confirmed this using openssl x509 -in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ISRGRootX1selfsigned.crt -text -noout).
placed it in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates (it's the only file there).
edited /etc/ca-certificates.conf and commented out mozilla/ISRG_Root_X1.crt
used sudo update-ca-certificates and sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh to rebuild the cert "db".
checked the results using:


openssl version -d returns /usr/lib/ssl.
ll /usr/lib/ssl returns certs -> /etc/ssl/certs/.
ll  /etc/ssl/certs/ |grep -i isr only returns info about ISRGRootX1selfsigned.pem and ISRGRootX1selfsigned.crt as expected, no other files/certs.

However, as stated before, openssl still tries to verify ISRG Root X1 using DST Root CA X3...
So, my question is,
how can I further debug this?
:-)

removeing/commenting out "mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt" in "/etc/ca-certificates.conf"
and rebuilding using "update-ca-certificates --fresh"
solved the problem.
( but I can't explain why).
